# Jira plugin create sample software project

Tags: jira, jira-plugin, jira-rest-api

I followed the tutorial at https://developer.atlassian.com/docs/getting-started/set-up-the-atlassian-plugin-sdk-and-build-a-project to install the Atlassian SDK and start building some plugins :) All good no issues there; however, I can only create "Business" projects. I would like to create a sample "Software" project. How can I do that? Do I have to install it under a different configuration? Do I need license...?

Comment: did you try asking in their community?  https://community.developer.atlassian.com/t/welcome-to-the-community/84

Comment: Just did :) thanks